# Color in between lines - table

Tags: tables, color, tabulary

I wanna make a table with colors. How I do a table with colors that only the interleaved lines have color?

Comment: Please read [the comment on your other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303453/how-i-make-this-table#comment735577_303453). Are you using `tabulary`? How? What do you mean by 'interleaved lines'? Do you mean every other row? Or do you mean the lines between the rows/columns? In any case, a minimal example showing your set up is really needed for anybody to say anything at all helpful.

Comment: Also, you have asked a number of questions and some of these have received several, often extensive answers. Please consider accepting answers to some of your existing questions. You can do this by clicking on the greyed-out tick at the top left of the answer you want to accept. Generally, this should be the answer which most helped you.This helps other users identify useful answers and is the local way of saying 'thank you' to people who've assisted you.

Comment: By "interleaved lines", do you mean "alternating lines"?

Answer (score 1):

Package `colortbl` of David Carlisle provides `\arrayrulecolor`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\toprule
Header\\
\midrule
abc\\
def\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]