# How do I make this table?

Tags: tables

I need to create a table with a specific aspect. How did I create the table that I annexed to this message?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,float}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]    
\centering    
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}    
\toprule    
 & Para os 10 per\'{i}odos & Medida (valor final)/ 10 per\'{i}odos &
 Para um per\'{i}odo & Medida (valor final)\\    
\midrule    
\hline M\'{e}dia & 14,04 & 14,04 & 1,404 & 1,40\\    
\hline Desvio Padr\~{a}o & 0,095770401 & 0,10 & 0,0095770401 & 0,01\\
\hline N contagens & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12\\    
\bottomrule    
\end{tabular}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey there :) I don't think you've successfully attached your desired table to this post, but in any case, you should quote the full error message you received and also show us what you've done so far. This last bit is really important, not just because it shows us that you've actually tried and makes us feel less like an unpaid typesetting service, but because it may also give us a starting point and, if you include a full MWE, shows us what packages you're using and your setup, which could drastically alter how we approach the question and what works and what doesn't!

Comment: Good, that's better, and you were right to edit it into the original question, I was just about to ask you to do that, but you should really make it into a full MWE, with your preamble and a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}`

Comment: @Au101 I make this code until now, but the table is out of the page and the table is not very appealing. I don't like the space between the first and the second line in the table and the table is very basic.

Comment: @jon If I put only \ give me error.

Comment: @jon I apologize if I did misunderstand. The point is that the table comes out of the sheet and there is a space between the first and the second line, I dislike but do not know how to draw. I would also tips to the table to stay more attractive because I find it very basic for a report that I have to deliver.

Comment: You are using rules from `booktabs` with both `\hline`s and vertical lines - I'm not surprised the result doesn't look very good! Did you look at `booktabs`'s documentation?

Comment: And do please consider accepting answers for some of your existing questions.

Comment: @Au101 -- Ah, I see. Will delete comments ... because, as I now think, there's actually no error, just a desire for a nicer table.

Comment: @Au101 Not only is the part of the aspect that interests me (is obviously also important), but the table is also out of the page and do not know how to change it.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález, if you're writing Portuguese, stop using those weird accent codes, just use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and type the accents normally.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I would do is load `geometry` which will use slightly more sensible margins than LaTeX does by default. Since the table is too wide, you have a few options:

1. make the text of the table smaller e.g. with `\small` or `\footnotesize`;
2. rotate the table using options from, of example, the `rotating` package;
3. allow cells to break within columns;
4. add notes to the table for supplemental information;
5. reduce the spacing;
6. some combination of two or more of the above.

(1) and (5) will make the table harder for readers. Especially, I would recommend not doing (5) and, if you do use (1), don't do it to excess. `\small` may be acceptable if you are using a reasonably sized font. `\tiny` probably won't be.

In the table below, I use (3) and (4). For (3), I use a `tabularx` environment consisting of one `l` column and four `X` columns. I then use (4) to move some information into a table note using `threeparttable`. Note that I don't have much idea of the meaning as I don't speak the language. So my selection is based purely on the punctuation and you may well wish to move something different into the notes. But this should at least demonstrate how to do that.

Follow the `booktabs` guidelines as these are good for at least 98% of cases, probably more:

- `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` (+ `\cmidrule{}` if required in more complex tables);
- no vertical rules;
- no double horizontal rules and, certainly, no `\hline`s.

`\toprule` and friends are designed to *replace* `\hline` etc. - they should not be used *as well*.

So these changes produce something like the following result:

[image: modified table]

It would be better, really, if the numbers were aligned on the decimal point. However, I had better leave that to the `siunitx` experts as I can only manage it for very simple cases.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,float,geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx,threeparttablex}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
      \toprule
      & Para os 10 per\'{i}odos & Medida\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} / 10 per\'{i}odos & Para um per\'{i}odo & Medida\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}\\
      \midrule
      M\'{e}dia & 14,04 & 14,04 & 1,404 & 1,40\\
      Desvio Padr\~{a}o & 0,095770401 & 0,10 & 0,0095770401 & 0,01\\
      N contagens & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[\textasteriskcentered]valor final
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- Use fewer significant digits - What information is conveyed by `0,0095770401` which isn't also conveyed by, say, `0,009577`?
- Keep using `c` as the column type for the numbers in columns 2 to 5, but use a column type that allows automatic line wrapping for the text in the header cells. I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment, set its overall width to `\textwidth`, and use a centered version of the `X` column type for the 4 header cells.
- I see no need for the interior `\hline` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l cccc @{}}
\toprule
& \mC{Para os 10~per\'{i}odos} 
& \mC{Medida (valor~final)/ 10~per\'{i}odos} 
& \mC{Para um~per\'{i}odo} 
& \mC{Medida (valor~final)} \\
\midrule
M\'{e}dia         & 14,04   & 14,04 & 1,404    & 1,40\\
Desvio Padr\~{a}o & 0,09577 & 0,10  & 0,009577 & 0,01\\
N contagens       & 12      & 12    & 12       & 12\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As supplement to @cfr answer:

- for column heads are used macro `thead` from package `makecell`
- for aligning of numbers at decimal point is used `S` column type from package `siunitx`
- instead of `tabularx` is used ordinary `tabular` environment

With this changes you can obtain:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools,float,geometry}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,tabularx,threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=3.11]S[table-format=4.3]}}
      \toprule
    &   {\thead{Para os 10\\ per\'{i}odos}} 
        &   {\thead{Medida\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} / 10\\ per\'{i}odos}}
            &   {\thead{Para um\\ per\'{i}odo}} 
                &   {\thead[b]{Medida\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}}\\
      \midrule
M\'{e}dia           & 14,04         & 14,04 & 1,404         & 1,40  \\
Desvio Padr\~{a}o   & 0,095770401   & 0,10  & 0,0095770401  & 0,01  \\
      N contagens   & 12            & 12    & 12            & 12    \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[\textasteriskcentered]valor final
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Caveat:* I'm not a `siunitx` expert, I only use it frequently ...

**Edit:**

Considering Mico comment let be noted:

- by loading of the `geometry` package the `\textwidth` is automatically increases from 360pt to 430pt. This means, that for table is with it more apace, i.e. the numbers with 11 decimal places can be set in full lenght. Otherwise, it had to be rounded on less decimal places, for examplt to five as manulay did Mico in his answer
- with option `table-auto-round` in combination with for example `table-format=3.5` the numbers in table is rounded to five decimal places and shorter numbers padded with zero to the given number of decimals
- with `siunitx` option `output-decimal-marker={,}` the decimal marker is changed from dot to coma (as seems that the OP appears to wish to use commas.

To better see the influence of above consideration an table layout, I add `showframe` package and center table on text width. The complete renewed code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont}
    \usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

    \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=3.5,
                            table-auto-round]S[table-format=4.3]}}
      \toprule
    &   {\thead{Para os 10\\ per\'{i}odos}}
        &   {\thead{Medida\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} / 10\\ per\'{i}odos}}
            &   {\thead{Para um\\ per\'{i}odo}}
                &   {\thead[b]{Medida\tnote{\textasteriskcentered}}}\\
      \midrule
M\'{e}dia           & 14,04         & 14,04 & 1,404         & 1,40  \\
Desvio Padr\~{a}o   & 0,095770401   & 0,10  & 0,0095770401  & 0,01  \\
      N contagens   & 12            & 12    & 12            & 12    \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[\textasteriskcentered]valor final
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Obtained result:

[image]

Comment: You may want to state somewhere that loading the `geometry` package automatically increases `\textwidth`, from `360pt` to `430pt`. If `geometry` weren't loaded, the table would be too wide for the text block. One way to fix this, i.e., to make the table fit in the text block even if `geometry` isn't loaded, would be to show fewer places after the decimal markers in columns 2 and 4. Incidentally, one should set the option `output-decimal-marker={,}`, as the OP appears to wish to use commas rather than dots to as the decimal markers.

Comment: @Mico, I consider your comment (+1 for it!) and edit my answer.