# Want to table fit in the sheet

Tags: tablenotes

How I make this table more attractive for the reader? (because the The reader cannot read the numbers of the table and I wanna want the table fit in the sheet).

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{mathtools,float}
\begin {document}
\subsubsection{Tabela que relaciona o per\'{i}odo com o comprimento do fio e 
que cont\'{e}m o resultado de todas as m\'{e}dias e desvios padr\~{a}o para os 
v\'{a}rios comprimentos do fio:}
\begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
\centering
\scalefont{0.75}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
\toprule
L - comprimento do fio (m) & M\'{e}dia do Per\'{i}odo (s) & Desvio Padr\~{a}o da 
m\'{e}dia & N$^{\circ}$ contagens & Per\'{i}odo ao quadrado ($s^2$) & 
$log\;L$ & $log\;T$\\
\midrule
0 & 0 & & & 0\\
\hline 0,4500 & 1,5278 & 1E-04 & 16 & 1,8616 & -0,7985 & 0,3107\\
\hline 0,5750 & 1,5280 & 1E-04 & 18 & 2,3345 & -0,5534 & 0,4239\\
\hline 0,6550 & 1,5278 & 1E-04 & 9 & 2,6576 & -0,4231 & 0,4887\\
\hline 0,7100 & 1,5281 & 5E-04 & 33 & 2,8917 & -0,3425 & 0,5309\\
\hline 0,7550 & 1,5276 & 1E-04 & 17 & 3,0804 & -0,2810 & 0,5625\\
\hline 0,8550 & 1,5282 & 4E-04 & 20 & 3,4767 & -0,1567 & 0,6230\\
\hline 0,9500 & 1,5294 & 1E-04 & 13 & 3,8310 & -0,0513 & 0,6716\\
\hline 1,0870 & 1,5273 & 2E-04 & 21 & 4,4019 & 0,0834 & 0,7409\\
\hline 1,1500 & 1,5278 & 1E-04 & 16 & 4,6393 & 0,1398 & 0,7673\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[\textasteriskcentered] Nota: $log$ neste caso corresponde ao logaritmo neperiano
\end{tablenotes}
\caption{Representa\c{c}\~{a}o dos dados finais para todos os ensaios realizados do p\^{e}ndulo simples}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good to see some code in this question, but this code will not compile. Please edit your question to make your code compilable.

Comment: @cfr Sorry for the errors on my code. I missing the packages.

Comment: To see if your code is compilable, try compiling it. If you get an error when you compile, chances are we will, too.

Comment: @cfr Sorry for make undo. When you say to me that I have to edit the question I make the modifications, but I fail. Yes, the English is not my first language, but every time I fail, correct me, I always wanted to learn English :)

Comment: @cfr I change the code. Try now, please.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. That compiles now ;). So how do you want to change it? I would get rid of all the `\hline`s. But apart from that, what do you wish to do? You could rotate it. Or you could make the headers multi-line.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. The table is fantastic. I will put this table in my report, is very beautiful and professional.

Comment: barbara is right about the numbers, though. You should look at the example Zarko provided to your other question. Also, you have several questions now with multiple answers, often quite detailed. Please consider accepting answers for your earlier questions. (Not this one: it is too soon.)

Answer (score 2):

I would rotate the table. However, if you do not want to do that, I would do something like the following.

- Do not scale fonts, especially those which come in multiple optical sizes. The shape of the letters at smaller sizes is not the same as the shape at larger sizes. 0.75 of 12pt is not equivalent to 8pt. Computer Modern and Latin Modern both feature multiple optical sizes, as do other high quality font families. *especially* don't scale a font to 0.75 when it is already `\scriptsize`.
- Personally, I would not use the `H` specifier. If you don't want something to move, don't make it a float. You can use `\captionof` from `caption` or `capt-of` if you nonetheless need a caption. I let tables float, but `\captionof` is a perfectly reasonable alternative.
- Don't use an excess of horizontal lines.
- `tabularx` can be used with a custom `X` column specifier for the first 5 columns to get multiline headers, effectively.
- Use `geometry` to get less excessive margins and a larger `\textwidth`.

This produces something like the following:

[image: possibly improved table - different, anyway]

I would also recommend aligning the columns according to the relevant number format. `siunitx` can help with this and with the correct typesetting of SI units and number formats generally.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin {document}
\subsubsection{Tabela que relaciona o per\'{i}odo com o comprimento do fio e que cont\'{e}m o resultado de todas as m\'{e}dias e desvios padr\~{a}o para os v\'{a}rios comprimentos do fio:}
\begin{table}
  \scriptsize
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{5}{C}cc}
    \toprule
    L - comprimento do fio (m) & M\'{e}dia do Per\'{i}odo (s) & Desvio Padr\~{a}o da m\'{e}dia & N$^{\circ}$ contagens & Per\'{i}odo ao quadrado ($s^2$) & $log\;L$ & $log\;T$\\
    \midrule
    0 & 0 & & & 0\\
    0,4500 & 1,5278 & 1E-04 & 16 & 1,8616 & -0,7985 & 0,3107\\
    0,5750 & 1,5280 & 1E-04 & 18 & 2,3345 & -0,5534 & 0,4239\\
    0,6550 & 1,5278 & 1E-04 & 9 & 2,6576 & -0,4231 & 0,4887\\
    0,7100 & 1,5281 & 5E-04 & 33 & 2,8917 & -0,3425 & 0,5309\\
    0,7550 & 1,5276 & 1E-04 & 17 & 3,0804 & -0,2810 & 0,5625\\
    0,8550 & 1,5282 & 4E-04 & 20 & 3,4767 & -0,1567 & 0,6230\\
    0,9500 & 1,5294 & 1E-04 & 13 & 3,8310 & -0,0513 & 0,6716\\
    1,0870 & 1,5273 & 2E-04 & 21 & 4,4019 & 0,0834 & 0,7409\\
    1,1500 & 1,5278 & 1E-04 & 16 & 4,6393 & 0,1398 & 0,7673\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[\textasteriskcentered] Nota: $log$ neste caso corresponde ao logaritmo neperiano
  \end{tablenotes}
  \caption{Representa\c{c}\~{a}o dos dados finais para todos os ensaios realizados do p\^{e}ndulo simples}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: those should be minuses in the *log L* column, but they're hyphens.

Comment: Yes, well if I knew how to format the numbers properly, I'd probably do it. However, the OP has already got examples of how to format numbers in tabulars using `siunitx` (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303462/) and isn't using that approach, so I guess it is not wanted by the OP.